# Ruby: Convert int AND store into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

In my first ruby hw assignment I have to make a FizzBuzz program. (If an int is / 3 its converted to a "Fizz" string, if divisible by 5, a "Buzz" string, and if by both a "FizzBuzz" string.) Lastly, if not divisible by either I need to convert the number itself to a string AND store it into an array in a method named main.

```
class FizzBuzz
  def initialize(int_num, str_fb, value)
   self.int_num = int_num
   self.str_fb = str_fb
   self.value = value
  end

  def int_num
   @int_num
  end

  def int_num=(num)
   raise TypeError if not num.is_a? Integer
   @num = int_num
  end

   def str_fb
    @str_fb
   end

  def str_fb=(name)
    if int_num % 3 == 0
      int_num = "Fizz"
    elsif int_num % 5 == 0
       int_num = "Buzz"
    elsif int_num % 5 == 0 and int_num % 3 == 0
       int_num = "FizzBuzz"
    else
      str_fb = int_num.to_s     #Also needs to be stored in an array in main function
  end


  def main
    ary =array.new
  end
end
```

How do I store the newly converted int_num (now a string) into the array in main? Also, the code above is only one method of the class, but does it appear correct? Thanks, I am a full blown Ruby noob and appreciate all the help.

**Added full code. Still incomplete, as I need to create a getter and setter for value that loops 1-50.

Comment: I think it is fine since OP already showed us their attempted code, which frankly is like 90% done anyway.

Comment: I'm just asking for help... I didn't know that wasn't allowed..? Professor recommends this site. For learning. Couldn't find a similar question, so I asked it.

Comment: Can you put _all_ your code up in the question as to give a better idea of your approach...

Comment: I'll take a look, but notice that your code won't even run because you are missing an `end` in your `str_fb` method.

Comment: This is definitely a keepable question. It may not be an _excellent_ question, but it's certainly acceptable, no need to close the question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to an array using `push` method or `<<` (shovel) operator. I prefer the latter.

Here is my take on your assignment:

```
module MyModule
  class FizzBuzz
    attr_reader :main

    def initialize(range)
      raise TypeError unless range.is_a? Range
      @main = []
      range.to_a.each do |i|
        main << process(i)
      end
    end

    private

    def process(num)
      if num % 5 == 0 && num % 3 == 0
        "FizzBuzz"
      elsif num % 3 == 0
        "Fizz"
      elsif num % 5 == 0
        "Buzz"
      else
        num
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I don't have any getter and setter methods. This is for two reasons:

1. The by calling the `attr_reader` class method, I am setting up a public getter method for main in a much more elegant way
2. I don't see a need for any setter methods as passing in the range when I initialise the class would is sufficient

If you save this module in a file named `my_module.rb` and run the irb command you can interact with your class as follows:

```
➜  Code irb
irb(main):001:0> require "#{absolute_path_to_file}/my_module"
=> true
irb(main):004:0> include MyModule
=> Object
irb(main):005:0> FizzBuzz.new(1..15).main
=> [1, 2, "Fizz", 4, "Buzz", "Fizz", 7, 8, "Fizz", "Buzz", 11, "Fizz", 13, 14, "FizzBuzz"]
irb(main):006:0> FizzBuzz.new('abc').main
TypeError: TypeError
    from /Users/username/Code/my_module.rb:6:in `initialize'
    from (irb):6:in `new'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/alexveldtman/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE: After looking at the code again, I thought it would be cool to refactor the class a bit to get rid of those boring if statements.

```
module MyModule
  class FizzBuzz
    attr_reader :main

    def initialize(range)
      raise TypeError, 'not a Range' unless range.is_a? Range
      @main = []
      range.to_a.each do |i|
        main << fizzbuzzerize(i){|fizzy_string, k| string_or_num(fizzy_string, k) }
      end
    end

    private

    def fizzbuzzerize(num)
      yield [divisible_by_3?(num), divisible_by_5?(num)].compact.join, num
    end

    def string_or_num(string, num)
      (string.length > 0 ? string : nil) || num
    end

    def divisible_by_3?(num)
      num % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : nil
    end

    def divisible_by_5?(num)
      num % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : nil
    end
  end
end
```

Note: the fizzbuzzerize method yields to a block in stead of returning a value

Comment: where do I loop from 1-50 in your suggestion of the assignment? I'm not quite sure I understand it fully. And I'm still confused on how to send the string directly into an array

Comment: ah, sorry. I think I misunderstood what you need to do - let me try again

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, just put the variable you want to return inside an array into brackets:

```
def main
  [str_fb]
end
```

Lots of other Ruby-specific improvements could be made here. For starters, you can replace the `int_num` and `int_num=` methods with a single line: `attr_accessor :int_num`. (You would need to move your `raise` to the constructor.)

You can replace the `str_fb` method with another single line: `attr_reader :str_fb`.

In the constructor, it is more common in Ruby to use instance variables to store input parameters. Consider which methods you want to leave public and which to make private. You can make instance methods (including `attr_accessor` and `attr_reader` private by adding a single line `private` and moving those methods below it.

So your code might look like this:

```
class FizzBuzz

  attr_accessor :int_num
  attr_reader :str_fb, :value

  def initialize(int_num, str_fb, value)
    raise TypeError unless int_num.is_a?(Integer)
    @int_num = int_num
    @str_fb = str_fb
    @value = value
  end

  <public instance methods here>

  private

  <private instance methods here>

end
```